# "You can't parse HTML with regex" WHY?

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

I know My question seems Like duplicated([duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags))...
But exceptionally I'm not trying to parse a "True/Valid" HTML, its a part of javascript variables / or of HTML tags, see my example:

```
                <td width="10"></td>
            <td ><div id="combo_rub" style="CURSOR:pointer"></div><input type="hidden" id="rech_cod_cat"  name="rech_cod_cat" value="1"/></td>
            <td ><div id="combo_typ" style="CURSOR:pointer"></div></td>
            <td ><div id="combo_sou_typ" style="CURSOR:pointer"></div></td>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            d_rech_cod_rub       = "101";
            d_rech_cod_typ       = "1";
            d_rech_cod_sou_typ   = "1020121";

            //ComboBox sous_type
            var z_sou_typ=new dhtmlXCombo("combo_sou_typ","rech_cod_sou_typ",160);
```

So what i want in my code PHP is to retrieve the value of(`d_rech_cod_rub`, `d_rech_cod_typ`, `d_rech_cod_sou_typ`) from Javascript part, not from HTML as you can see...

the second scenario is:

```
<td><a href="AnnoncesImmobilier.asp?rech_cod_rub=101&amp;rech_cod_typ=1">
<font color="#2154eb">Location (6920)</font></a> </td></tr></table></td></tr>
<tr><td><table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr>   
<td><a href="AnnoncesImmobilier.asp?rech_cod_rub=101&amp;rech_cod_typ=5"></td>
```

Same here i need to retrieve the '101' value...

Finally, The full story: I'm using very frequently the Curl extension of PHP then I come across    with a content like the above examples... the problem is when i use a HTML-Parser like (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) i can not done my work with this, because it work only with a valid HTML..:(
my question: there is any solution to retrieve the values in a stable manner ?
what are you doing if you come across a case like me ?

Thanks guys.

**EDIT** :  So according to most answers, using RegX do the trick...

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php

Comment: Use a more forgiving html parser. What do you think the browser is doing when it meets that html?

Comment: @Jocelyn: As i already said in my question is not a duplicated question, i'm not trying to parse a HTML tags, just a little part of text

Comment: Since your text is within a file containing HTML tags, I don't think using a regex is a good idea. This is what is explained on the page I linked to.

Comment: The problem with JS is almost exactly the same as the problem with (X)HTML.  JS is not a regular language (it's context-free, AFAIK), and REs tend to suck at parsing non-regular languages.  Past a certain point, even with our modern souped-up "RE"s, it's not possible...and even before that, you'll be tearing your hair out in frustration.  If you have a *known sample*, and are ok with not being able to tolerate deviations, then you can easily grab a specific chunk of text...but the more general you want it, the less useful REs get -- and the easier it is to use a real parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regexes do the trick

```
d_rech_cod_[a-z_ ]*= "([0-9]*)";
rech_cod_rub=([0-9]*)
```

Not sure about PHP but you might be able to evaluate it using the following code:

```
preg_match($regex, $content, $matches);
print($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is that value it is quite easy to use a regexp just for that:

```
d_rech_cod_rub\s*=\s*"([0-9]+)";
```

Where the first capture group is your value.

Comment: If you want it to work on all the d_rech variables you can add another capture group: `(d_rech_cod_[a-z_]+)\s*=\s*"([0-9]+)";`

Answer (score 2):

In a more specific answer, regular expressions cannot deal with nested information.

For example ...

```
<span>Hello <span>World</span></span>
```

A regular expression that looks for `<span>.*<\/span>` will return:

```
<span>Hello <span>World</span>
```

We won't even mention trying to process invalid HTML with missing tags.

Something like [this (`loadHTML`)](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) might be what you want instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether it's possible to do what you want with one regular expression, but certainly possible with one regular expression per variable. Also it's Possible to use `strpos` function to parse string. Here the second approach will probably be more efficient way.